# Inversion of the coefficients matrix of a linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

Consider a linear system of equations, $A*f=b$, where $A$ is the coefficient matrix, $f$ is the unknown vector of variables, and $b$ is a known vector. Is there any way to find the inverse of matrix $A$ knowing all $A$, $f$, and $b$.

Matrix $A$ is a general matrix and it does not have any specific property.

Also, is there any relation between the inverse of the matrix $A$ and matrix $B$ which is equal to $A$ plus a diagonal matrix ($C$) (i.e. $B=A+C$ where C is a diagonal matrix)?

Comment: This is what rank-1 and rank-2 updates in the Broyden and BFGS process are for. Using $k$ matrix-vector products you know rank-$k$ information and can compute a rank-$k$ approximation of the inverse matrix. See also Krylov spaces.

Comment: Also look up ILU and other pre-processing methods and the CG conjugate gradient method. What no-one does with large systems is to compute the inverse matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that$A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $f$ and $b$ arecolumn-vectors with $n$ positions. First ,$A$may not have an inverse, in which case either there is no solution, or there are infinitely many solutions. There is a unique solution iff $A$ has an inverse. $A$ has an inverse iff $\det(A) \ne 0.$ If $\det(A) \ne 0$ then 
$$A^{=1}=\frac {1}{\det(A)}(\text {cof} (A))^T$$ where cof($A$) is the matrix obtained by replacing every element of $A$ by its cofactor.If $A^{-1}$ exists, then $$f=A^{-1}b.$$

Comment: As I mentioned, $A$, $f$, and $b$ are known. I have a fast solver to find $f$ and there is always a solution. Thus, $A$ is invertible. I am looking for a way to find $A^{-1}$ in terms of these known matrices. The direct solution does not work. $A$ is a large matrix (about 100000*100000).

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of elementary row-operations? If $A$ is invertible, it is row-equivalent to the identity matrix. This means there is a finite number of elementary row-operations applied to $A$ which leads to the identity matrix. Each of such operations can be represented by left-multiplication of $A$ by an invertible matrix.

If $A$ is not invertible, it is still row-equivalent to a reduced row echelon form, from whence you can determine if there is or there is not a solution.

The advantage of this method lies on the fact that the same elementary row-operations applied to the identity leads to the inverse of $A$. Indeed, we have $PA = I = A^{-1}A$. Multiplying both sides by $A^{-1}$, one has that $PI = A^{-1}$.

I prefer this method because it is less laborious than calculating the determinant of $A$ and the corresponding cofactor matrix. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Operations) is a quick reference on the subject. I advise you to look for it.

Comment: I don't know about the method you mentioned. But it is not what I am looking for. 
I am looking for $A^{-1}$ in terms of $A$, $f$, and $b$. $A$ is always invertible.
 I think it is an interesting problem. We know when $A$ is invertible there is a unique solution. So, it must be a relation between the $A^{-1}$ and the known  $A$, $f$, and $b$.

Comment: P.S. I appreciate it if you have any idea about the second question.